# As shown in the figure, from these 2 table I want to select a record from 1st table if only if 'is_verified' field in 2nd table contain null or 1

Tags: mysql

As shown in the figure, from these 2 table I want to select a record from 1st table if and only if `is_verified()` field in 2nd table contain all nulls or mixture of nulls and 1s against a particular `review_id`.

[image]

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, I have attached it but don't know why its isn't visible. please click on the question to view it

Comment: COALESCE(is_verified,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this but check change the column name and table as you have in database.

**For specific review id:**

```
Select * from table1 a
Inner join table2 b ON a.id = b.review_id
WHERE ( b.is_verified IS NULL OR b.is_verified = 1) AND a.id = 5049
```

**For all reviews:**

```
Select * from table1 a
    Inner join table2 b ON a.id = b.review_id
    WHERE ( b.is_verified IS NULL OR b.is_verified = 1);
```

**If one of them 0 skip record:**

```
Select * from table1 a
    Inner join table2 b ON a.id = b.review_id
    WHERE 
AND b.is_verified != 0
AND a.id = 5049
```

**Anti JOIN EXAMPLE (will skip all others):**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Table2 AS t2
        WHERE t2.reviewer_id = t1.id
          AND t2.is_verified = 0
      )
```

Comment: First thing, as highlighted in figure tables should be joining on id=review_id  not user_id.
Secondly that I want same query for each id in table1.

Comment: Join updated for second one remove id = 1 in where clause u will get all record

Comment: Updated as u need seperatley

Comment: @saddam you can use it seperatley

Comment: There is no 5049 id in your both table @saddam but I have updated it in my answer check my ist query

Comment: For example: For ID=5049 in table1, there exist 3 rows in table2.
Table2:
id        review_id     is_verified
5264      5049          null 
5265      5049          1
5266      5049          0

In this case Query should return empty. It should only return a single record if all 3 are either null or (nulls+1s). If any value against particular id is 0, it should return empty

Comment: I know id 5049 is not in this table but i  have create an example scenario  in my last comment which is my actual requirement

Comment: 5049 have one record is null and 2 records are 0 and u need all three correct me? Or u just need those record who have is verified equal 1 skip null and 0 status records

Comment: @saddam now check query one it will return 2 records now like you have three records against 5049, 1, 0 and null..... my ist query will skip the one record that is verified equal to 0

Comment: I want to skip all records if one of them is 0

Comment: @saddam now check my third query