# How to check multiple rows values at once to retun something in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a scenario in which i want to retrieve records from one table but based on some condition. Suppose the table 1 has following records

[image]

and table 2 has following records

[image]

The column review_id is a foreign key from table 1.  I want to select ID's from table1 on the basis of a 'is_verified' field in table2. Select if all values against a particular ID is either all null or mixture of nulls and 1s. if any value is 0 the result for that particular ID should not be selected.
For given example data above:
ID 5052,5051,5048 should be returned and 
5053 should not be returned because out of 4 values one value is 0 in table2 for ID=5053.

Comment: I guess it's just serendipity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479066/as-shown-in-the-figure-from-these-2-table-i-want-to-select-a-record-from-1st-ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.review_id = t1.id and
                        t2.is_verified = 0
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon